# Can I use a JSP template without an HTTP servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I want to use a template with a markup standard such as JSP to create an HTML formatted string based on data from a bean or a bean container.

Essentially, I just want a standalone service that will take a JSP formatted template and a POJO and return an HTML string.

```
public String generatePage(String jspFormattedString, List<Object> data){
   ..some stuff
   return htmlString;
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: + you may use any other template solution like velocity, freemarker, twirl etc.

Comment: I've used freemarker in a limited capacity before but from what I remember I would have to create my own (proprietary) syntax for the template. Is there a way to have freemarker use an actively maintained markup (such as JSP) so I don't have to add all of the functionality myself? I'm not the one writing the templates, so I'd rather use something that's already standardized.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Use a JSP engine like [GnuJSP](http://www.klomp.org/gnujsp/), [Apache Jakarta](http://jakarta.apache.org/) or [Resin](http://www.caucho.com/). There's a tutorial how to use [Jasper 2](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/jasper-howto.html) engine with an ant task to compile the JSP pages.

Comment: That's excellent news! I see that the Jakarta project was initially a set of in development projects that have (for the most part) gotten moved to TLPs. When you say Jakarta here, are you talking about the Tomcat server? Is there an ability to use compiled jsp classes with the apache libraries without specifically installing a webserver?

Comment: Take a look at the Jasper 2 engine which allows for compilation of JSP pages using an ant script. Once compiled they can be used with some input to generate the HTML.